# How to reduce "add up" to "add"?

Tags: nlp

I'm new to NLP; Searching for something that reduces some "words" like "add up","sign up","log in", etc. to their main part "add", "sign", and "log".

I tried Lemmatization and Stemming, but none of them brought me the results that I wanted to have.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This looks quite peculiar. You don't usually get [phrasal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) out of a NLP pipeline as a unit. You need to give more detail: What exactly is your input (and where do you get it from)? The way you present the data now, the answer would be simply "delete the second of two words".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you try is to use a part-of-speech tagger to get the part-of-speech category for every word. You could then look for patterns in the part-of-speech sequence like "Verb, Preposition" to find the combinations you're looking for and then delete the preposition.